# Find the first element smaller or equal to a given number in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

| Numbers |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 5 |
| 10 |
| 15 |
| 23 |
| 25 |

Given column elements like above, how can i write a formula that gets me the biggest number which is smaller or equal to a given number (found in another cell)?

For eg: for input 11, the formula should return 10

EDIT: Correction to the expected return value.

Comment: *for input 11, the formula should return 0* This makes no sense. Did you mean 10?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns, Yes. 10 sorry. I corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

`=MAX(A2:A7*(A2:A7<=11))`
Excel prior to 365 need to enter the array formula with `ctrl+shift+enter`

The part `(A2:A7<=11)` creates an array of TRUE and FALSE which converts to 1 (TRUE) or 0 (FALSE). Multiplied by the values in range `A2:A7`. So all false conditions result in value * 0 = 0. True conditions result in value * 1 = value. So running that though `MAX` returns the max value with condition.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in my question. expected result is 10.

Comment: I figured that. This formula returns the correct value (10 in this case)